# Determine the spectrum of $T$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $p\in (1,\infty)$. Let $T\in B(l^p)$ be the forward shift operator defined by $T(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...)=(0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...)$. Determine the spectrum of $T$.

So clearly $0$ is in the spectrum since $0.I-T$ is not onto. And I think $0$ is the only element in the spectrum. Am I correct? If I am wrong can somebody please help me to determine it?

Comment: Try to solve $(\mu I - T)(x) = y$ for $\mu \neq 0$. Does it work? Do you get a continuous inverse?

Comment: I got that $T^{-1}(\mu_1,\mu_2,...)=(\mu_1/\mu,(\mu_2+\mu_1/\mu)/\mu,...)$. But I don't know how to check the continuity of this.

Comment: Look at $y = (1,0,0,\dotsc)$ first. That settles a lot of it.

Comment: Ok then $T^{-1}(y)=(1/\mu,1/\mu^2,1/\mu^3,...)$. So spectrum is unit disk right?

Comment: Open or closed? And why doesn't the spectrum contain any $\mu$ with $\lvert \mu\rvert > 1$?

Answer (score 2):

One can see immediately with no computation that this cannot be correct using general theory.

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital Banach algebra and let $A\in \mathcal{A}$.  Then,
>   $$
> \sup \{ |z|:z\in \sigma (A)\} =\lim _m\| A^m\| ^{1/m}.
> $$
>   (This supremum is called the **spectral radius** of $A$.)

In this case, $T^m$ is just the operator that shifts the index by $m$ (instead of just by $1$), and so $\| T^m\| =1$ (it's an isometry).  Thus, the spectral radius is $1$.  (For example, you can find this as Proposition VII.3.8 in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.)

In fact, it turns out that
$$
\sigma (T)=\{ z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|\leq 1\} ,
$$
though no element is an eigenvalue.

To see this, we use the fact that $\sigma (T)=\sigma (T^*)^*$ (we do this because $T^*$ has eigenvectors, which are straightforward to compute).  First note that $T^*$ is the backward-shift operator.  Then, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda |<1$, a computation shows that $T^*(v_{\lambda})=\lambda v_{\lambda}$ where $v_{\lambda}\in \ell ^p(\mathbb{N})$ is the vector with $[v_{\lambda}]_n=\lambda ^n$, that is, the $n$-component of $v_{\lambda}$ is $\lambda ^n$.  (Note that $v_{\lambda}$ is indeed an element of $\ell ^p(\mathbb{N})$ because $|\lambda |<1$.)  Thus, $B_1(0)\subseteq \sigma (T^*)$, and hence $D_1(0)=\operatorname{Cls}(B_1(0))\subseteq \sigma (T^*)$, and hence $D_1(0)=D_1(0)^*\subseteq \sigma (T^*)^*=\sigma (T)$.  However, we saw above that the spectral radius of $T$ is $1$, and so $\sigma (T)\subseteq D_1(0)$.  Thus, $\sigma (T)=D_1(0)$.

Finally, I mentioned above that $T$ doesn't have any eigenvalues.  To see this, simply write down the defining condition $T(v)=\lambda v$ and see what this implies about $\lambda$ and $v$.  This defining condition reads:  $0=\lambda v_0$ and $\lambda v_n=v_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$.  If $\lambda \neq 0$, this implies that $v_0=0$ and $v_n=\frac{v_{n-1}}{\lambda}$.  These together imply that $v=0$, and so no nonzero $\lambda \in \sigma (T)$ is an eigenvalue.  On the other hand, $\lambda =0$ is not an eigenvalue because $T$ is injective.

(Regarding notation, $B_r(z_0):=\{ z\in \mathbb{C}:|z-z_0|<r\}$ is the *open disk* and $D_r(z_0):=\{ z\in \mathbb{C}:|z-z_0|\leq r\}$ is the *closed disk*.)